# Search and replace in multiples files at once by having them all open as a buffer?

Tags: search, replace

I've done this before in emacs but I can't remember how or which plugins were involved.

Basically you marked a bunch of files according to a file extension, and then you got asked for a search string, and finally it **opened all files that matched the string as a long list of buffers/windows.**

This entire list of buffers/windows was easy to modify as ordinary text after which you could save them all to save the changes.

I've searched for "search replace multiple files in emacs" but all the results seem to point to a replace behaviour that is static rather than having all the files as actual buffers.

So the question is, which plugin or command may this have been?

Comment: The basic facilities that are built into emacs are described in the manual: `C-h i g(emacs)Searching and replacing with identifiers`. Also, `multi-occur-in-matching--buffers` can be used for searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `helm-ag`.

More info here: https://yamadapc.github.io/posts/emacs/workflow/2015/03/11/using-helm-ag.html